# Should I have both Iphone 4 and Iphone 5 device for testing or iphone 5 will suffice in ios development

Tags: ios

I recently got the iPhone 5 and I was thinking if it would be ok to discard my old iPhone 4. 
Is there a possibility an app wont work on different devices given they have the same iOS version?

Comment: i cannot see any reason to __not__ test it on iphone 4 and you already have one

Comment: @xlc I think he wants to sell the iPhone 4

Comment: The more different environments you test on the better -- I've seen several cases of different behavior between phone or iOS versions.

Comment: it will save you lots of trouble when your app crashed on your customer's iphone 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the number of questions that get posted here, the biggest possible issue is making sure your user interface presents itself properly on the two differently sized screen.

I think you are fairly safe if you test on a real iPhone 5 and you also test your user interface using the 3.5" iPhone simulator.

tl;dr - you are safe to have just the one real device if you use the simulator for the other.

Update: I suppose I should point out, as others have said, that more devices are better. It really depends on the type of app. Games should be tested on more hardware. Utility apps can be properly tested on less real devices. As long as you understand the needs of your app and the limitations of the simulator, you can do what you need.

Plenty of apps are in the store that were never tested on any real devices. Most were tested on one device. Not many people have multiple devices. Every single original iPad app was tested without a real iPad. No one had one yet at the time.

We must all deal with reality. If you have the device, great. If you don't, you do what you can.

Comment: @Downvoter - please educate everyone. Why do you think this answer is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a possibilty an app wont work on different devices given they have the same ios version?

Yes. They have different hardware, which means it will *at least* behave differently, and there's always the possibility of OS bugs on specific hardware. A few things come to mind:

- **RAM:** The iPhone 5 has about 1 GB, the iPhone 4 has 512 MB, and the 3GS has 256 MB. A memory-heavy app that gets killed on the iPhone 3GS might work just fine on the iPhone 5.
- **GPU performance:** The iPhone 5 has a much beefier GPU; things which look okay on the iPhone 5 might be unacceptably slow on the iPhone 4.
- **CPU performance:** There's a speed increase and also an architecture bump (`armv7s` vs `armv7`), but the biggest difference is that the iPhone 5 has two cores, which means it will be able to do lots of processing on a background thread without significantly affecting the UI thread.
- **Camera:** If you use `AVCaptureSession`/`AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and friends, expect different behaviour on different devices. The most obvious is that the iPhone 5 supports 1080p video while the iPhone 4 only goes up to 720p, but there have also historically been many differences: the iPhone 3G only properly supports `2vuy`/`BGRA` whereas all newer devices support `420v`/`420f`/`BGRA` instead. There was also a bug with the 3GS running 4.1 or 4.2 (I forget which) where asking for `420v` would cause a hang, but not setting a format would cause it to default to `420v` and work.

You should also test on multiple OS versions (ideally all supported OS/device combinations, except that's a bit costly).

That said, for the most part you can get away with using the simulator unless you use features that are only present on device.

Comment: Was the hardware specs above were simulated as well in simulator?

Comment: No, thats the problem with the simulator. In the simulator you get all the memory of your Mac. You get the Mac's CPU. You don't get a camera.

Comment: @AlbertOclarit The easiest way to accurately simulate the behaviour of an iPhone 4 is to use an iPhone 4. Do you really expect an accurate real-time simulation of the iPhone 4's CPU/GPU/camera on x86?